# How to write selenium webdriver automation scripts for Flex applications

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am in the process of writing automation scripts for Flex applications using Selenium-Web driver but i don't know exact steps and the ids capturing for Flex application.have goggled  several times but I couldn't get any exact solutions and answers.

Please let me know clear steps to write the automation scripts and capturing ids using any tool or from Selenium IDE.

Currently they provided me only application URL by using the application URL only I need to write the scripts using Web driver.

Answer (score 0):

Although this only works with Selenium 1 (not webdriver), take a look at Flex Monkey:

http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/flexmonkium

Install the console and then start up a selenium server, loading the user extensions provided in the zip file (also available on the download page).

If you open up the page you are testing and then open the console, the console should indicate it is connected - you will then see actions in the selenium IDE.

If not, you need to deploy the application under test with the appropriate SWC projects for Flex Monkey to recognise the objects on the page.

Comment: 404 - This tool is no longer supported as well by the company.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You are not able to automate Flex web app using webdriver (at least the easy way). You can do it with Selenium RC, adding FlexUISelenium extension to RC and compiling application with Flex libs.

I've heard about writing Your own javascript methods with flex handling, but I didn't try (will investigate it soon). 
[Check this link.](http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/21-automation-of-flex-applications.html)

However I do hope that I'm wrong, because I'm facing this problem now ;)